# Using AWS CLI cmd how to get only loadbalancer 443 Listener ID ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface, aws-application-load-balancer

Using AWS CLI cmd how to get only loadbalancer 443 Listener ID ARN ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-listeners.html !? And then filter the result.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output listed on [describe-listeners — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-listeners.html), the command would be:

```
aws elbv2 describe-listeners --query 'Listeners[].ListenerArn'
```

If you want the output as just text, with one entry per line, use:

```
aws elbv2 describe-listeners --query 'Listeners[].[ListenerArn]' --output text
```

The `--query` parameter uses JMESPath. I highly recommend the [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: Hi, Below mentioned is my cmd, i need to get a loadbalancer arn and need to pass it to the describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn to get a only one listerner arn, i tried but below mentioend cmd is not working.

`aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --names Test-ALB --output text --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn' | xargs -n1 aws elbv2 describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn $lb --query 'Listeners[].[ListenerArn]' --output text`

Comment: I suggest that you **ask a new Question** because this is raising other issues that are unrelated to this Question. When you create a new Question, please explain your _actual_ goal (that is, what you'd like to achieve) because there might be a different way to achieve that objective.